# Обособление части предложения с двух сторон тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

**Он уже знал, чего хочет – заработать больше денег, – поэтому решил, что нужно получить правильное образование.**

Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания? Если неправильно, то в чём ошибся и можете ли Вы привести ссылку на соответствующее правило, например, из Розенталя.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, правильно.
Вот у Розенталя:

> С помощью тире выделяются вставные конструкции, дополняющие или поясняющие основное предложение, выражающие чувства автора и т. д.

Здесь как раз пояснение. Чего именно хочет? Заработать больше денег.

А также:

> В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной
>   конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире,
>   могут быть еще запятые.

В Вашем примере запятой закрывается придаточное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Вставные конструкции (слова, словосочетания, предложения) содержат дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки и т. д. На письме вставные конструкции выделяются скобками или тире.
Вставки грамматически не связаны с предложением, расположены обычно в середине или в конце его (их можно "изъять" без потери смысла):

*Десять лет назад Подгорин — он был тогда бедным студентом — преподавал Надежде математику и историю…* (Чехов)

На месте разрыва предложения ставится сочетание знаков (запятая и затем тире), если запятая нужна по условиям контекста:

*Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — прошёл к окну* (В. Каве­рин).
Запятая закрывает обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное одиночным деепричастием.

В Вашем предложении пунктуация правильная, запятая перед вторым тире необходима.
(Без вставной конструкции: *Он уже знал, чего хочет, поэтому решил, что нужно получить правильное образование*.)

[**Знаки препинания при вставках**](https://info.wikireading.ru/69114)

Answer (score 0):

Есть предположение, что здесь (по Розенталю) надо ставить **одно тире:**

**Он уже знал, чего хочет – заработать больше денег,  поэтому решил, что нужно получить правильное образование.**

Это **не вставная, а пояснительная конструкция** (раскрывается содержание местоименного слова), то есть дается не дополнительная, а основная информация. Если её убрать, то будет непонятно, чего же он хочет.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится **тире**: Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать — почитать (Г.); Разговор шёл один — о погоде; То ли он решил, что **ошибся — честного человека не распознал**, то ли по другой причине, но он охотно выполнил просьбу.

Comment: Я полностью согласен, но Вы не обосновали отсутствие второго тире (пояснительная конструкция должна обособляться). Думаю, обособление имeет смысл в пределах того предложения (в составе сложного) , к которому пояснительная конструкция относится, поэтому второе тире не нужно.

Comment: Я ориентировалась здесь на Розенталя с его примером, поэтому не стала углубляться в тему. Пояснительные конструкции, вероятно, обособляются по образцу приложений (там тоже одно тире в пределах простого предложения в составе сложного). Это как раз два типа обособления: вставка с двумя тире и встроенная конструкция с одним тире.